# Layering background images in FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm making a layout in FXML using CSS to create the background, but I'd like to layer one background on top of the other (the top one having transparency) and I can't find any API to do this. Is it possible? (I can't combine them together, the top is static where the bottom is modified using css)

Answer (score 0):

By programing i don't know the way to achieve this...you can done it by **`stackpane`** and two image view of same size images..

try this i hope its work..

Image 1 : - bottom potion

[image: Image down side portion]

Image 2 : - Uppar Portion

[image: Image Uppar side portion]

```
@FXML
private StackPane stpane;

AnchorPane anch = new AnchorPane();


@FXML
void initialize() {
    assert stpane != null : "fx:id=\"stpane\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'TestImageTransparent.fxml'.";
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Koala1.png")));
    ImageView ivs = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Koala.png")));
    stpane.getChildren().addAll(iv,ivs,anch);
    iv.setOpacity(0.3);

    Button btn = new Button("StackOverflow");
    btn.setLayoutX(120);
    btn.setLayoutY(200);
    //set your css stying according your need
    anch.getChildren().add(btn);
    }
```

Final View -

[image: Final View]